# Can't access property in PHP date object

Tags: php

I'm creating a datetime object with:

```
$datetime = date_create_from_format('Y-m-d\TH:i:sP', $string);
```

Which gives an object with properties `date`, `timezone_type`, and `timezone`. But I can't access any of these properties:

```
return $datetime->date;
```

This returns `null`. What am I doing wrong?

Edit:

var_dump($datetime) gives:

```
object(DateTime)#807 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(19) "2015-04-14 13:28:06"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(1)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(6) "+00:00"
}
```

Comment: Provide a `var_dump()` of such object.

Comment: What does `var_dump($datetime)` output?

Comment: Are you sure [these properties exist](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)?

Comment: I've added it to the original post.

Comment: Try to access other properties instead of date and see. Because 'date' is keyword in php.

    $datetime->timezone_type

Comment: But it will print the `$mydate->date;` 

     $date = new DateTime( '15-Feb-2009' );
     var_dump( $date->format( 'r' ) );
     var_dump( $date );
     var_dump( $date->date );

it shows the `$date->date` after `var_dump` because php lazy initialization

right way to do this use `$date->format('r')`

Answer (score 1):

There is [Bug issue](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=49382) regarding this in php. You cant access it directly. Use `format` method. Try with -

```
$datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? Please add an explanation of what you did and why you did it that way not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO. (Why can't he access it directly?)

Comment: @Rizier123 it is a bug. What shall i explain more?

Comment: Maybe explain what a "bag" is...  *@Rizier123 it is a bag*